# iOS using the same xib for multiple ViewControllers

Tags: ios, inheritance, uiviewcontroller, xib

I'm creating an app and starting to run into a problem that the size of my app is getting pretty big and I'm looking for ways I can decrease the size. I have over 50 xibs so I think that's one of the areas I can improve on. I have a lot of xibs that are all matched up to a different View Controller eacbh and some of them are very similar.

I'd like to be able to take these similar ViewControllers, and reuse one xib for all of them to cut down on size.

I'm thinking inheritance would be the best way to do this. Create a "SuperViewController" that all my other ViewControllers extend. The SuperViewController will be hooked up to the xib and then I could reuse what I need.

Here's what I have in the SuperViewController.m:

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *emptyView;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *currentButton;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *quitWalkButton;
```

All of those IBOutlets are in my xib files and are in all of my ViewControllers. Each ViewController just does slightly different things with those.

Problem is, because these are in my .m file they are essentially private and I can't access them from the subclasses. I could put them in the .h file and be able to access them, but I don't want them public I want them "protected". Also, I'm not sure how actions like click will work because those are always in the .m file.

I'm beginning to think that Inheritance isn't the way to go to reuse xib files in multiple View Controllers, but I'm not sure what's the accepted way to do this. Any advice either way is appreciated.

Comment: Create the view controller dont set file owner for this... Put the tag for all the subview add the xib file in viewDidLoad and access the xib file subview using its tag...

Comment: So are you saying load nib files pragmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd leave those outlets right where they are at the top of the .m file of the superclass, and put a second accessor for each in a separate header/ extension.

```
   //myViewControllerSuperclass+privateOutlets
     # import "myViewControllerSuperclass"
     @interface myViewControllerSuperclass(privateOutlets)

    //this header to be imported to your subclasses
     @property (readonly) UITableView *tableView_;
     @property (readonly) UIView *emptyView_;
     @property (readonly) UIButton *currentButton_;
     @property (readonly) UIButton *quitWalkButton_;
    //note trailing underscore..



//myViewControllerSuperclass.m
# import "myViewControllerSuperclass+privateOutlets"
@implementation myViewControllerSuperclass

#pragma mark - privateOutlets
-(UITableView *)tableView_{
return self.tableView;
}
-(UIView *)emptyView_{
return self.emptyView;
}
-(UIButton *)currentButton_{
return self.currentButton;
}
-(UIButton *)quitWalkButton_{
return self.quitWalkButton;
}
//these 'getters' just point to the existing outlets..
```

Comment: So with this I could make the File Owner of the xib file be myViewControllerSuperclass, right? And then when I have actions set up like a click action that is wired to myViewControllerSuperclass, how would I be able to override that?

Comment: 1. yes
2. let's say self.currentButton is hooked up to -(IBAction )buttonAction:sender;... well your subclass can override buttonAction: and do whatever (new thing)  it wants to do with it....

Comment: when I do this my subclass ends up having a blank screen. I override initWithNibName and nil is passed in. How can I make the subclass get the nib?

Comment: why pass in nil for nibName?  if you override that at all then do nibNameOrNil = @"mySuperclassNibFile";  [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil ....]
if you do this then ALL subclasses will use this nib always..

Comment: I meant the argument is coming into that method as nil, but I just realized it always comes in as nil for all my working ViewControllers. What I was missing though was actually passing in mySuperClassNibFile name in that method and passing it to super. Works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In apps I've seen, the large consumer of space is the media, not the XIB data. Large images, video, audio, etc. eat up space pretty quick.

If something is actually consuming space inside the XIB's it might be easier to find it by viewing the XML inside the file rather than looking at Xcode' visual editor. You may find large blocks of binary data.

Comment: I do have some media, but the amount is very small. Really though, I have so many xib files and view controllers that despite any size, it's getting too hard to manage. There has to be a better way for doing reuse.